# 404 error using urllib but URL works fine in browser AND the full web page is returned in the error

Tags: python-3.x, http-status-code-404, urllib

I'm trying to open a web page in python using urllib ( to scrape it ).  The web page looks fine in a browser but I get a 404 error with urlopen.  However, if look at the text returned with the error, it actually has the full web page in it.

```
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    try:
        html = urlopen('http://www.enduroworldseries.com/series-rankings')
    except HTTPError as e:
        err = e.read()
        code = e.getcode()
        print(err)
```

When I run the code, the exception is caught and 'code' is '404'.  The err variable has the complete html that shows up if you look at the page in a browser.  So why am I getting an error?

Not sure if it matters but other pages on the same domain load fine with urlopen.

Comment: The provider of that resource "http://www.enduroworldseries.com/series-rankings" is returning 404 when you access that page. That may be a way to stop people accessing/scraping the page using code such as yours. You may want to look into properly preparing your user agent and so forth, so it looks like you are accessing the page from a browser and not from code.

Comment: I've tried setting the 'User-Agent' to 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}). Didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution without knowing what the initial problem was.  Simply replaced `urllib` with the `requests` library.

```
req = Request('http://www.enduroworldseries.com/series-rankings', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'})
html = urlopen(req)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Became

```
response = requests.get('http://www.enduroworldseries.com/series-rankings', {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```